# Who loads the data of a process into the register bank which is in the data path?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture

When a process is in the running state and for example lets say we want to add two numbers therefore the instruction register will have the instruction to add two numbers (Add two registers in the register bank).

My question is who loads the data into the register bank to be added by the ALU?

Comment: Normally this would be done by previous instructions executed by the process itself.  How else?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks I got it now. Os is really confusing

Answer (score 1):

The hardware is an instruction set interpreter.

You can think of an interpreter written in C as a loop something like this:

```
unsigned int *PC = START_ADDRESS;
while ( 1 ) {
    unsigned ir = *PC++;
    switch ( ir >> 24 ) {
    ...
    case 0 :
         unsigned regA = (ir & 0x1F0) >> 5;
         unsigned regB = (ir & 0x7E) >> 10;
         unsigned answer = registerFile[regA] + registerFile[regB];
         unsigned regC = (ir & 0x1F00) >> 15;
         registerFile[regC] = answer;
         break;
    ...
    }
}
```

The hardware is similar except that it can do many things in parallel.

So, the operation of `ir = *PC++` is typically considered part of "Instruction Fetch".  The complexity of this varies dramatically, from simple in early MIPS where the instruction size is fixed at 32 bits and pipeline only 5 stages, to very complex on x64 with variable length instructions, long pipelines, intermediate caches of instruction decode (micro ops), and other parallelisms and complexities.

The + operation in `answer = registerFile[regA] + registerFile[regB]` is part of the ALU operations, and the fetch of operands, as in `registerFile[regA]` is sometimes referred to as part of "Instruction Decode".

There will be wires that do the register file indexing to fetch the value held in the register and feed them to the ALU.

Because the ALU can source from registers or immediates, there are control signals that allow only the proper source through to the ALU.

Comment: Its just a program written in hardware.

Comment: can you tell me how this program is executed?
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a=2;
int b=3;
int c-a+b;
return 0;
}

I know when i will compile it will produce a binary and when i will execute it dynamic adress binding will happen;
so lets say i have int a=2 and int b=3 in main memory. now when int c=a+b this is an arithmatic operation so the data 
 2 and 3 is needed to be loaded in the register bank for the addition operation to happen. I am confused about the part that who loads the data 
into ther register bank and how the result is stored bak in the main memory?

Comment: For such a simple program, the compiler would compute the result at compile time and then remove all code.  Actually, I'm serious.  But assuming you forgo optimization, these constants, 2 & 3 would probably be loaded using immediate address, which is to say that the 2 & 3 are literally stored in machine code instructions, which are stored in memory for execution.  The rest depends on the overall architecture you're looking at, as for example, x64 and RISC V are rather different in the actual machine code instructions that would come from this program.

Comment: You can use godbolt.org to look at how different instruction sets/architectures do different things.  It will show you the machine code for a given C program, and that machine code will be run by a hardware program that is an interpreter of the instruction set.

Comment: This site is just gold thanks a lot . I under stood now after watching the assembly code.